# while deleting the contact it is showing final Exception

Tags: salesforce

I want trigger on contact where if,I have one account with Multiple contacts while deleting one contact should not delete i have throw before delete the record

```
set<ID> accSet =new set<Id>();
    for(contact c:conOldList){
        if(c.AccountId !=NULL){
            accSet.add(c.AccountId);
        }
    }


    list<Account> accList=[select id,name,(select id,Account.Name from contacts) from Account where ID IN:accSet];
    for(Account a:accList){
        list<contact> conlist=a.contacts;

            if(conlist.size()>0){
                a.addError('Do not Delete');
            }

        }
```